# New SharePoint WFE Build - When should I patch?

Tags: installation, cumulative-update, configuration-wizard, service-pack

I am building a new SharePoint 2013 farm, and have built and configure the server that will host central admin.

This has been patched with Service Pack 1, and the July CU.

I have also run the basic install of SharePoint 2013 on my two web front ends, and they are currently waiting for me to run the "Products and Config" wizard. I plan to do this once I've set up the base portal and relevant services.

The question I have, is at whcih point should I patch the two WFE's with SP1 and the July CU?

Would I be able to patch these both now, and just skip the products and config wizard for the time being?

Comment: You should always patch and upgrade the servers during the same time, otherwise you will start to see different errors when the servers are not at the same patchlevel. You can install the patches to all the servers at the same time and then run the wizard on one server at the time to apply the patches. No wizard = no patch applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to patch the servers to the same version that is currently running on the servers in the farm before you can join them to the farm.

In otherwords, your farm is running SP1 + July CU, so you need to install SP1 and the July CU on the WFEs before joining them.

There is no need to run the config wizard to complete the upgrade when patching servers that are not joined to a farm, as there are no associated databases that would need upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following things

- Install the SharePoint + SP1 + Latest CU on all servers in the farm( App server and WFEs).
- Run the Config wizard on the central admin server and build a farm.
- Configure the state service.
- Now Run the Config wizard on the WFEs one by one and join them in the farm.
- once all server in the farm, now I will start configuring the Services applications, Web applications etc.

this is recommended approach and tested by me tons of time.